# what cd burn lib for app development libburn

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Hi I am developing a GTK front end for playing audio files, encoding them then burning audio cd's. I have playing and encoding implemented but have run into a wall with burning.

I would rather not call wodim or the likes in a spawned system() call. But after days of research have yet to come up with a suitable cd burning lib.

Most libs seem to be dead or unmaintained forks and those not dead seem close to dead when checking there current activity levels.

Libburn seems to be the most promising but the documentation etc also seems out of date with much talk of 2.6 kernel use.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks in adavnce
Milo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't worry about kernel 3.X not being mentioned.
The last big change of the SCSI passthrough mechanism was in 2.5.
So the documentation talks of old 2.4 versus new 2.6.

More problematic nowadays may be demons which believe to
own the CD drive. Escpecially when burning CDs you do not
want to have an unattended process to grope your drive.
The workarounds for this regrettably change every other year
by the introduction of new gropers or heavy overhaul of 
the old ones.

As for audio burning, see test/libburner.c and its option --audio.

One thing that is not working is our mailing list.
Send support requests to bug-xorriso@gnu.org or in private to
scdbackup@gmx.net.